# Converting String to datefield / Java Microedition

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

Using J2ME, netbeans 7.2, Developing a mobile app..

I have converted the Datefield value to a String and Now want to put it back to a Datefield. To do this I need to convert the String back to Datefield, I am using the following code but its not happening.

```
long myFileTime = dateField.getDate().getTime(); // getting current/set date from the datefield into long
         String date = String.valueOf(myFileTime); // converting it to a String to put it back into a different datefield

         Date updatedate= stringToDate(date); // passing the string 'date' to the Method stringToDate() to convert it back to date.
                 dateField1.setDate(updatedate); // updating the date into the new datefield1

public Date stringToDate(String s) 
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)));
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5)) - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 10)));

    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify what is the format of the myFileTime variable? Is it 25122012 for 25 DEC 2012 ?

Comment: it is in this format '25122012' plus the time.

Comment: I think that the reason your code is not functioning well, is that because the `long myFileTime` is not in the format you are thinking. When you do `Date.getTime()` it returns you the miliseconds after January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT and not a long in the format of 25122012. In that case the below code sample will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you have the `long myFileTime` around, you should be able to use:

```
Date updatedate=new Date(myFileTime);
```

To convert back to your date. If only your `String` is available, you should modify your function to this:

```
public Date stringToDate(String s){
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

  c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2)));
  c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2, 4))-1 );
  c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4, 8)));

  return c.getTime();
}
```

Note the changed indexes.

In Java SE, you should be able to use  the following line, instead of setting each fields separately:

```
c.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(s));
```

Since in `s` you have the `dateField.getDate().getTime()` that is equal to `myFileTime`, the number of seconds starting with January 1, 1970, based on your provided code.

Your `stringToDate` should work only if your string will have the following format: `ddMMyyyy`. Also note that in this case you should use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse, something like:

```
Date updatedate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(date);
```

Comment: I understood, I have time as well. So you meant to use only the above line instead of all the set items in stringToDate() method ?

Comment: I am not able to get SimpleDateFormat, unable to add library for that. Using J2ME so...

Comment: @raam030 You can do either, see my updated answer. If you have the `myFileTime` around you should use `c.setTimeInMillis`.

Comment: I am getting an error when used c.setTimeInMillis, says 'no suitable method found for 'parseLong(long)'...

Comment: @raam030 `Long.parseLong(s)` needs a `String` not a `long`. If you already have the `long` you can use directly: `c.setTimeInMillis(your_long)` or even simpler `new Date(your_long)`

Comment: -1 in java ME MIDP/CLDC, [Calendar.setTimeInMillis](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29) is `protected`, as opposed to public in Java SE. Also, there's no SimpleDateFormat there - [no `java.text` package at all](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/overview-summary.html)

Comment: @raam030 See my updated answer, some of your initial indexes were drifted a bit.

Comment: its taking my long and updating the datefield correctly. Thanks for the help Dan. Such a simple thing I was thinking too much !!!!....Thank you all...                                           long myFileTime = dateField.getDate().getTime();
          date = String.valueOf(myFileTime);Date d = new Date(myFileTime);
                dateField1.setDate(d);